# Auto insert characters into an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to insert auto characters into an `EditText`? I have `addTextChangedListener` method. Input type is `numberDecimal`. I try to add 0 if input starting .(dot) I want to get like this result (0.4,0.3 etc). I wrote this code but it's not working.

```
 countunicoinsSell.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            countCourse(s.toString());
        }
    });


   private void countCourse(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return;
    if (value.startsWith(".")) {
        countunicoinsSell.append("0");
    }

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: change this `countunicoinsSell.append("0");` to `countunicoinsSell.setText("0."+value);`

Comment: this will cause two dots i guess

Comment: just need to do this countunicoinsSell.setText("0"+value);

Comment: the functionality you want is called `mask`. There are a lot of libraries for that. For example https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText . More can be found here https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=masked+edittext+android&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for your try it out!

```
etMobileNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!s.toString().contains("0.")){
                etMobileNumber.setText("0.");
                Selection.setSelection(etMobileNumber.getText(), etMobileNumber.getText().length());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(s.toString().startsWith(".")){
                // append with 0
                mEditText.setText("0" + mEditText.getText().toString());
                // move the cursor to the end of the string
                mEditText.setSelection(mETEmail.length());
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value.startsWith(".")) {
    countunicoinsSell.setText("0"+value);
}
```

Comment: Please, avoid code only answers and explain your solution.